# Pythonic way of editting list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I write the code which works for me. But I wonder if I could write in a better way.

My purpose is find first elements in dataR which value of "col" key is equal to dataS element and adding 1 to value of "quan" key . dataR is a list of dictionaries. dataS is a list.

```
for item in dataS:
    dataR[dataR.index(next(x for x in dataR if x['col']==item))].['quan'] += 1
```

Comment: can you show us how the original `dataR` looks like?

Comment: like [{'col': 'K2', 'quan': 0}, {'col': 'K7', 'quan': 3}, {'col': 'K11', 'quan': 4}] It is read from SQL.

Comment: and what does this mean: *'..which are equal value of "col" key..'*? Do you want to modify all that have a key called `'col'`?

Comment: I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to lookup the row by index, you already have it:

```
for item in dataS:
    first_row = next(row for row in dataR
                     if row['col'] == item)
    first_row['quan'] += 1
```

`dataR` is the name for a sequence of `dict` objects. `first_row` is a name we give to one of the objects in the sequence. If we modify that object using that name we will modify the object in the sequence named `dataR`. No copies are made. In python to make a copy of an object you usually have to be explicit.

Comment: does this make sense to you `if data['col'] == item:`? If this ever evaluated to `True`, this data structure would be infinitely nested.

Comment: There is one trick. Not all elements  which data['col'] == item will be change. Only first found element will change.

Comment: @PeterWood I want to understand python working style. Firstly your code is working. I think same way before. But   at " first_row = next(row for row in dataR if row['col'] == item)" , after transfering to first_row, how dataR changed. Is next return special type of variable? Is connection between dataR and first_row ensured by copy?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `item` is from `dataS`, `data` is from `dataR`

Comment: @PeterWood Oh, I missed that...Thanks